# Browser runs faster than webdriver selenium command

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, jmeter-plugins

I am performing an operation using selenium webdriver to wait for an element until an element is visible. After a few milliseconds, it gets disappeared(Expected).Generally we use explicit wait to synchronize with browser because browser is slower. But in this case, browser is faster and before command waits for the visibility , the element disappears hence failing the operation.

It would be great if anyone can help regarding the issue.

PS I am using jmeter webdriver plugin.

Thanks.

Comment: What is your exact business requirement? For which condition do you exactly want to induce wait? Why are you waiting for `until an element is visible`? Does the element keep on appearing/disappearing at pre-defined intervals?

Comment: You will need to slow down the connection speed to test the visibility and invisibility of the element. Try it with a proxy server and throttle the connection speed in the proxy settings.

Comment: @Grasshopper IMO, here OP's main issue is with the selection of proper `ExpectedConditions`

Comment: Post your code and the before and after HTML.

Answer (score 1):

You could handle exception which breaks your validation (ignore `NoSuchelementException` but fail validation on `TimeoutException`) or create waiting method which waits for element to appear and after that wait to disappear.